# C# - Balloon Notification Working in Windows 8.1 and 10 but Not Windows 7

Tags: c#, notifications, notifyicon

I've been working on a feature for a personal project that has balloon notifications in the tray. The problem? They only work on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. In fact, these are notifications that slide out from the right side of the screen. I looked at the NotifyIcon's functions on MSDN and worked out my code through that. I'm not sure what's going on.

Here's the code that works on Windows 8.1 and 10

```
    private void CloseNotification()
    {
        var balloonNotification = new NotifyIcon()
        {
            Visible = true,
            Icon = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Information,
            BalloonTipTitle = "Alert!",
            BalloonTipText = "Program will remain running in the background",
        };

        //show the balloon notification
        balloonNotification.ShowBalloonTip(2);
        balloonNotification.Dispose();
    }
```

I call this this method when a button is pressed on my form.

What's going on?

Comment: If you remove the Dispose what happens?

Comment: Nothing in Windows 7, but has the same behavior in Windows 8.1 and 10.